# Is the nearest point on a level set always in the direction of the gradient?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Suppose I have a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ and consider two level sets
$$
\begin{align}
    L_1 &= \{x \,:\, f(x) = c_1\} \\
    L_2 &= \{x \,:\, f(x) = c_2\}
\end{align}
$$
Now take a point $p_1\in L_1$, and consider the nearest neighbour $p_2\in L_2$.

> Is it true that $p_2$ is always in the direction of the gradient at $p_1$? In other words, there always exists $\gamma \in\mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$
> p_2 = p_1 + \gamma\nabla f(p_1)
> $$

## Attempted Solution

Consider
$$
d(p_1, x) = \|p_1 - x\|^2 = \|p_1\|^2 - 2p_1^\top x + \|x\|^2
$$
I want to minimize this with respect to $x$ constrained with $f(x) = c_2$. The lagrangian is
$$
\mathcal{L} = d(p_1, x)  + \lambda(f(x) - c_2)
$$
Take the derivative with respect to $x$
$$
\nabla_x d(p_1, x) = -2p_1 + 2x + \lambda \nabla f(x)
$$
Setting this to zero gives
$$
x = p_1 - \frac{1}{2}\lambda \nabla f(x)
$$
But now the gradient is evaluated at $x$ for some reason.. which leads me to believe
$$
p_2 = p_1 + \gamma \nabla f(p_2)
$$
rather than
$$
p_2 = p_1 + \gamma \nabla f(p_1)
$$

#### Regarding regions of high curvature

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't say that $p_2 = p_1 + \nabla f(\color{blue}{p_1})$, because gradient in $p_1$ "doesn't know" what will happen outside of small neighborhood of $p_1$ - you can change $f$ pretty much in any way outside of this neighborhood, this will greatly affect $L_2$, but will not affect $\nabla f(p_1)$ at all.

For example, consider $f(x, y) = x / 2 + y^2$. Let $p_1 = (0, 0)$, then $\nabla f(p_1) = (1/2, 0)$. Now, taking $c_2 = 1$ we get $(0, 1) \in L_2$, so $d(p_1, p_2) \leq 1$, but closest point from $L_2$ in direction of gradient is $(2, 0)$, which is further from $(0, 0)$.

You can say that $p_2 = p_1 + \gamma \nabla f(\color{blue}{p_2})$, as your derivation shows. Intuitively, if $\nabla f(p_2)$ is not parallel to $p_2 - p_1$, then you can move a bit in direction orthogonal to $\nabla f(p_2)$ but not to $p_2 - p_1$ without changing $f$ but moving closer to $p_1$.

Comment: Mmm so what is wrong in my derivation?

Comment: Your derivation that shows $p_2 = p_1 + \gamma \nabla f(p_2)$ is correct. Intuitively, if $p_2 - p_1$ is not orthogonal to $\nabla f(p_2)$, then you can move from $p_2$ a little in direction orthogonal to gradient to be closer to $p_1$ while keeping value of $f$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Now I am very confused then. How can your answer and my derivation be correct at the same time?

Comment: Everything is getting very confusing now. I tried to taylor expand
$$
f(p_2) \approx f(p_1) + J_f(p_1) (p_2 - p_1)
$$
which tells me 
$$
c_2 - c_1 \approx J_f(p_1)(p_2 - p_1)
$$
In other words, for fixed $c_1$ and $c_2$, the larger the distance $p_2-p_1$ the smaller the gradient, which goes against everything I thought I knew. In regions of high curvature one should have a larger distance between the level sets. And regions of high curvature are characterized by large gradients

Comment: Updated the answer: your derivation is correct for gradient in $p_2$, not for gradient in $p_1$. For Taylor expansion - no, in regions of high curvature you have *smaller* distance between the level sets, because function changes faster and need less time to change significantly.

Comment: Thank you. I have added a picture (will remove later) to my question. In this case, I am considering two ellipses. At the left and right vertieces, the level sets are further apart, and that's where the higher curvature happens

Comment: Actually, curvature itself has not much to do with level sets - gradient shows you the slope (how fast function itself changes, which is inverse proportional to distance between level sets), and curvature shows change of the slope. For example, if $f$ is linear, its plot has zero curvature, but distance between level sets depends on slope. I am not sure, what does your ellipses represent, but if you consider say function $f(x, y) = x^2 + 2y^2$ (so ellipses correspond to level set), then parts where level sets are further apart are parts where curvature is smaller.